modules why don’t work in breakpoint swiperjs
I want to add navigation and pagination specifically on this breakpoint but it does not recognize the modules. By placing in the general outside of the breakpoint it works. I just don't want it to show up at all. Only when it encounters the breakpoint.
<Swiper
      slidesPerView={ 4}
      grid={{ rows: 1, fill:"row" }} //
      spaceBetween={10}
      breakpoints={{
        240: {
          slidesPerView: 2,
          spaceBetween: 0,
          grid: {
            rows: 2,
            fill: "row",
          },`your text`
          pagination: false,
          navigation:false,
        },
        768: {
          slidesPerView: data.length >= 4 ? 4 : data.length,
          spaceBetween: 10,
          grid: {
            rows: 1,
            fill: "row",
          },
          modules:[Grid,Pagination, Navigation],
          pagination:true,
          navigation:true

        },
      }}
      modules={[Grid]}
      observeParents={true}
      observer={true}
      watchSlidesProgress={true}
    >

Condition the pagination and navigation in the breakpoints
